# How to use Spatial Smoothing on relativities at postcode level in Python

Tags: python, spatial-index

I'm after some help with how I can use Spatial smoothing on my data which I have attached.

What I'd like is for neighboring postcodes to not have such a large difference in relativities.

Just to provide little more about these relativities - they are used in calculating the premium charged to a customer for home insurance.

I also have a postcode file which contains for all postcodes in the UK their longitude and latitude coordinates.

Please see attached a small subsection of my data for your reference.

[image: Attached picture shows relativities per postcode]

Comment: Welcome to SO! What have you tried so far? We're more here to help with questions of the form "I tried X, but it didn't work, instead I got error Y .. what happened?", accompanied by a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: Hi,

Sorry, I'm new to machine learning & this is my first ML project.

I haven't managed to try any code as I do not know a particular spatial smoothing technique that would work on my dataset

I've read around the topic and spoken to my manager who agrees I should do this. I was hoping to be pointed in the right direction to the type of Spatial smoothing technique to use which I could then try myself and see how I get on

I've read that maybe KDE or weighted average at say postcode sector level could work but I'm lost tbh as how to even start it

Thanks for any help you can give

Comment: @ti7 would it help if i attached my postcode file which contains longitude and latitude coordinates?